# How to get the max number of response in a GET request?

Tags: git, rest, powershell

I am invoking a GET request using Powershell.

```
$restresponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://bitbucket.org.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/projectname/repos"
$restresponse
```

In response it only returns 25 repos, but I have more than 200 repos.

```
    {"size":25,"limit":25,"isLastPage":false,"values":[{
    ..........
    .....
```

I can modify the `size` and `limit` like this:

```
$restresponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://bitbucket.org.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/projectname/repos?size=200&limit=200"
```

But, I don't want to follow this approach, as in future there will be more repositories and then again I have to manually change the size and limit.

Is there a way to retrive max size and max limit without hard coding the value?

Answer (score 1):

One adaptative solution is to fix a limit to N and loop increasing N while `size` equal `limit`. This is not very nice but you'll get the result in a few request event if the number of results increase.

Some servers works giving you back the URL to call for the next bunch of data.